# How to send the "chosen drop down option" to reciepnt and not the respective email id assiciated with it in contactform7?

Tags: forms, contact-form-7

I am creating a form using contactform7. I have to dynamically change the recipient depending on the "country" selected from the drop-down list. I have successfully done that by:

```html
[select* Recipient placeholder "Country" "China|sidraaleem1234@gmail.com" "Belgium|sidraaleem@alumni.sjtu.edu.cn" "Canada|sidra.aleem@emcc-China.com"]
```

Now, I want to send the country selected from the drop-down list to the email recipient. I have added [recipient] field in the message body under the mail tab of contactform7.

However, in the email, I get the respective email id of the chosen country from the drop-down as visible in the attached image. Though in drop-down I only added country names, not the email ids. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D5vP.png)

Can someone help me to send the only country names to the receiver and not the email id?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value after pipe character, put the usual mail tag corresponding to the form tag ([your-recipient] in the case of the above example) in the Mail templates. To get value before pipe, you can use [*raw*{field name}] ([_raw_your-recipient]

This is completely explained in the [Contact Form 7 Documentation](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/)

In your case, it's `[_raw_Recipient]`